# Can I run system gunicorn using dependencies in a venv

Tags: python-3.x, debian, gunicorn, python-venv

I am setting up a production environment with gunicorn on debian. [The documentation](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/install.html#debian-gnu-linux) suggests installing gunicorn using the system package manager instead of pip with somewhat compelling arguments, so I have, but I can't get it to work with dependencies inside a venv.

If I do

```
cd project
source venv/bin/activate
gunicorn project.wsgi # this is /usr/bin/gunicorn, not venv/bin/gunicorn
```

I just get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'`.

Any idea how I could get this to work? Or is this just a terrible idea (in which case I'm not quite sure why the gunicorn documentation even suggests this, I assume most people will have their project dependencies in a virtual env)?

Edit: I also tried using `--pythonpath` argument with gunicorn on a bunch of directories in the venv and kind of made some progress but it was obviously very hacky/frail/stupid so I'd rather just use gunicorn in venv if it comes to that

Answer (score 0):

*I know it's a late reply but I just ran into the same error, so it might help others too...*

**Solution:**

1. Install `gunicorn` with `apt install gunicorn3`
2. Install other python dependencies with `pip`
3. Get the site-packages folder(s) where `pip` installed the packages to (you might want to specify a different python interpreter than in the example below, e.g. if you're using a venv):

```bash
python3.11 -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages())"
```

4. Add this folder to the [--pythonpath](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#pythonpath). The following solved the problem in my case:

```bash
gunicorn [...] --pythonpath '/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages'
```

I'm not sure whether there is a cleaner solution if you're on Debian and need to use `apt` to install `gunicorn` (for me, installing it with `pip` didn't work, also not from the git source).